# How to group data in pandas when dealing with both categorical and continuous variables?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Customer_ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
      'Loan': [200, 250, 300, 400, 300, 500, 150, 150, 400, 250, 150, 300, 200, 200],
     'CustomerGender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
     'Agent_ID': [306, 306, 306, 306, 306, 307, 308, 308, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309], 
     'AgentGender': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M','M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
     'settlement_value': [23.5, 30.99, 306, 86, 50, 307.35, 1200.54, 25, 48.88, 400, 2100.10, 30, 1309.10, 500.50]}
```

I would like to aggregate them by Customer_ID.
Background info: There are six customers who took out loans multiple times offered by Agents (denoted by Agent_ID). Agents serve multiple customers. For example Agent with ID 306 provided loans to Customer 1 and 2. Similarly, Agent with ID 309 provided loans to Customer 5 and 6. I would like to aggregate the amount of loans each customer took and get something like in the table below. It is important I see the gender of the customer and agent after aggregation.

[image]

I tried the following code:

```py
# declare the two gender columns categorical. 

data['AgentGender']=data['AgentGender'].astype('category')

data['CustomerGender']=data['CustomerGender'].astype('category')

# transform to dataframe

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
# aggregate the data by Customer_ID to see the total amount of loan each customer took. The two gender variables do not appear when running this code.

data = data.groupby(data.Customer_ID, observed=True).sum().reset_index()


data 


# the following code aggregates the data and shows the two gender variables, only if I don't include the 'settlement_value'.

data1 = data.groupby(['Customer_ID','CustomerGender','Agent_ID', 'AgentGender'], observed=True)['Loan'].sum().reset_index()

data1

# if I include 'settlement_value', aggregation does not work at all:

data2 = data.groupby(['Customer_ID','CustomerGender','Agent_ID', 'AgentGender', 'settlement_value'], observed=True)['Loan'].sum().reset_index()

data2
```

Can you please help me fix this code?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
f = {'Loan': 'sum', 'CustomerGender': 'first', 'Agent_ID': 'first', 'AgentGender': 'first', 'settlement_value': 'sum'}
df.groupby(['Customer_ID'], as_index=False).agg(f)
```

returns
[image]

Comment: thanks for solving this issue for me! It seems to work on my big data - I have nearly 1 million rows and 50 columns.  I can't vote up your answer as I have not earned the credentials yet.

Comment: If you can select it as the correct answer (tick) that would be great :D

Comment: I've done it now scotmanDavid, I did not know about this. I would have given you a vote too, but my reputation is too low to vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'CustomerGender', 'Agent_ID', 'AgentGender'], observed=True).agg({'Loan': 'sum', 'settlement_value': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

```
   Customer_ID CustomerGender  Agent_ID AgentGender  Loan  settlement_value
0            1              M       306           F   750            360.49
1            2              F       306           M   700            136.00
2            3              M       307           M   500            307.35
3            4              M       308           M   300           1225.54
4            5              F       309           F  1100           2578.98
5            6              F       309           F   400           1809.60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.groupby(['Customer_ID','CustomerGender','Agent_ID','AgentGender'], observed=True).sum().reset_index()
```